# When should I tell my employer that I don't plan on staying after my internship?

Tags: internship, negotiation, employer-relations

I am a PhD student in the UK due to start a three-month internship in a startup within the next two weeks. When I was made an offer (a couple of months ago), the company pushed very hard to offer me a permanent position. I insisted on the three-months internship because this is my first job post-PhD.

After signing the contract (with the mutual understanding that if all goes well I will stay for a permanent position after the internship), I got an opportunity to spend three months in a research group. This is a professional opportunity that I absolutely **do not** want to pass on, so I accepted, and am due to start right after the three months internship.

When should I tell the startup bosses that I am definitely leaving for three months after the internship? Depending on how it goes I wouldn't mind then coming back to the startup and taking on a permanent role, so I would like to roll this out in the best way possible.

**UPDATE** I ended up telling them during my second week, mentioning it as an opportunity I hadn't yet accepted but did not want to refuse, and asking them how open they would be to a delayed start to my permanent contract. They served me my notice immediately, and seem intent in giving me no meaningful work for the next month. In hindsight, I should have told them much later, as that would have given me two more paid months.

Answer (score 5):

**Talk with your manager now, there's little to gain by waiting, but there is a lot to lose by not giving as much notice as you can.**

Some things you should consider:

1. **Give as much notice as possible.** Give your manager a chance to keep critical work that you're working on going after you leave. If the organization knows you're leaving, other colleagues can overlap with you on your work to avoid delays due to unplanned handovers.
2. **Share your aspirations with your manager.** The company may be willing to be accommodating (e.g., give you 3 months of leave to pursue the research). If coming back after your research experience is something you're open to - start the conversation now to see if that might be possible.
3. **In general, honesty and transparency yield the best results.** Keeping your intention to leave to yourself is a risk.  Your colleagues and manager learning about your departure from someone else increases the risk of "burned bridges."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should I wait until I have actually started working there? Or send an email to start the conversation now? I was hoping to at least start on a project before letting them know - I am a little worried about this putting them off giving me any meaningful work.

Comment: Give your future manager a call before you start.  You should also share your expectation to have an opportunity to advance meaningful work even though you are not intent on staying.

Comment: I ended up telling them almost immediately after I started, mentioning as an opportunity I really wanted but hadn't yet accepted. They served me my notice immediately, and seem intent on giving me no meaningful work to do for a month.

Answer (score 1):

What is the notice period for your internship?

If there is a mutual understanding that you would convert to full time at the end of your internship, then that notice period length is the smallest amount of time you can give your manager while remaining professional.

When you give your notice, be sure to tell them about the research group that you're leaving for. You don't *need* to do this (and in fact you don't owe them any explanation of why you're leaving at all), but if your manager is a reasonable person then they'll understand the value of the opportunity to you, and won't begrudge you taking it.

If you've given an appropriate amount of notice, and made it clear that you're not leaving because you don't like the company, then you're unlikely to have burned any bridges and your manager may be open to offering you employment at the end of your research group period.

Comment: " to start right after the three months internship" Op is never going to hand in a resignation. The internship will simply end.

Comment: @FooTheBar if the OP wants to leave the possibility of future employment on the table (as they've stated that they do), and the manager expects that the OP will continue at the end of the internship (as stated in the question) then dropping the "I'm not coming back tomorrow" bomb at the end of the internship won't be a very good choice.

Comment: @PlayerOne I think what Foo is trying to say is that there won't be an official notice period in place as it's a fixed length contract

Comment: @Bee the fixed term contracts I've signed before all had notice periods

Comment: @PlayerOne those notice periods are for quitting within the contract. I've never heard of a fixed contract that stating a notice period after the contract expires.

Comment: @SanderSkovgaardHansen My point is that since the manager expects him to stay, then not giving notice (even though notice will not technically be required) will not leave the manager in a good position (as they are planning ahead on the assumption that the OP will continue and become a permanent employee). If the OP would like a chance at working for that manager again (as they've said they do), then it would be best not to burn them on their way out the door.

Comment: @PlayerOne I completely agree, I'm just saying, that the sentence "the fixed term contracts I've signed before all had notice periods" is misleading at best, malicious at worst. Your original point is perfectly fine.

Comment: @SanderSkovgaardHansen I respect your point, but I don't think there's anything malicious in that sentence. For what it's worth, I actually _did_ give the manager at my last fixed term contract notice that I would not be available to renew it when it expired, precisely because I wanted to make sure I left on good terms.

Comment: @PlayerOne I applaud your decision and would do the same and again, I really do find your advice solid.